# General way to transform S4 object to dataframe (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, r-s4

I have a number of S4 objects with a variable number of slots and slotnames. The data in each slot is the same length. For example the S4 object `peaks`:

```
> str(peaks)
Formal class 'MassPeaks' [package "MALDIquant"] with 4 slots
  ..@ snr      : num [1:16] 37.81 9.18 8.65 4.66 53.22 ...
  ..@ mass     : num [1:16] 307 317 325 337 347 ...
  ..@ intensity: num [1:16] 2255 547 516 278 3173 ...
  ..@ metaData : list()
```

I want to turn these S4 objects into dataframes. For example the dataframe `df.peaks`:

```
> str(df.peaks)
'data.frame':   16 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ snr      : num  37.81 9.18 8.65 4.66 53.22 ...
 $ mass     : num  307 317 325 337 347 ...
 $ intensity: num  2255 547 516 278 3173 ...
```

Is there a general way to do this? For this example I can do

```
> df.peaks = data.frame(snr=peaks@snr, mass=peaks@mass, intensity=peaks@intensity)
```

but that requires hardcoding the slotnames of the S4 object. **How do I do it without hardcoding the slotnames?** I could do it by getting `s4.names = slotNames(peaks)`, but in this case I don't know how to use `s4.names` to access the slots of `peaks`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about the "right" way to do this, as I very rarely use S4 objects. Here's a stab at it though:

```
# from the ?slot page
setClass("track", slots = c(x="numeric", y="numeric"))
myTrack <- new("track", x = -4:4, y = exp(-4:4))
str(myTrack)
```

> ```
> Formal class 'track' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 2 slots
>   ..@ x: int [1:9] -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4
>   ..@ y: num [1:9] 0.0183 0.0498 0.1353 0.3679 1 ...
> ```

The approach here is to get the slot names, and then iterate over them one at a time, extracting into a list of the contents of each slot. Then give the list-elements the appropriate names (from the slots), and bind it into a dataframe.

```
# conversion function
S4_to_dataframe <- function(s4obj) {
  nms <- slotNames(s4obj)

  lst <- lapply(nms, function(nm) slot(s4obj, nm))
  as.data.frame(setNames(lst, nms))
}


S4_to_dataframe(myTrack)
```

> ```
>    x           y
> 1 -4  0.01831564
> 2 -3  0.04978707
> 3 -2  0.13533528
> 4 -1  0.36787944
> 5  0  1.00000000
> 6  1  2.71828183
> 7  2  7.38905610
> 8  3 20.08553692
> 9  4 54.59815003
> ```

Comment: Yes! `slot()` is exactly what I was missing.